# Swap Curve and Forward Libor Rates

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, yield-curve, interest-rate-swap, libor

How does the (interest rate) swap curve incorporate **forward** libor expectations?

Comment: This question is not obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap rate can be viewed as a weighted average of the forward rates. The forward rates would incorporate expectations of future rates, so should a swap rate then. Now a swap paying/receiving LIBOR against fixed rate is a weighted average of the forward LIBOR rates, and hence your statement.